# Paid my tax online, but received a non-payment notification from the IRS

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs

I filed my Federal taxes correctly as a Non-resident using 1040NR-EZ form, and I had to pay a certain amount.
I paid online using payusatax.com (on-time) but used the "pay 1040 balance due" option. I made a mistake in assuming it covered all 1040 forms.

The money got debited, and I got a confirmation number, too.
2 months after, I got a notice from IRS saying I haven't paid my taxes and I need to pay it by a certain date with a penalty.

How do I rectify this mistake? Will I need to pay it again, or will IRS be able to redirect it properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a number of scams based on people pretending to represent the IRS. Make sure you know who you are dealing with. https://www.irs.gov/uac/newsroom/phone-scams-continue-to-be-a-serious-threat-remain-on-irs-dirty-dozen-list-of-tax-scams-for-the-2016-filing-season

Comment: Another good summary of what to suspect and how to check/report it: https://www.irs.gov/uac/report-phishing

Comment: @keshlam It was not a phishing attempt on my part I guess, since the payment has been verified by payUSAtax.com . Does me paying for the wrong from matter? 1040 instead of 1040NR-EZ?

Comment: I would have guessed that you would be in the clear and paying for 1040 instead of 1040EZ should not matter. But, I was curious how this all worked out for you.

Comment: @KevinFegan It worked out fine. It turns out the IRS people "forgot" to take the money as they had put a flag on it since it was my first time paying taxes. I started laughing on the call when they actually said "forgot"! And yes, it seems it does not matter what form you pay for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to [contact payUSAtax.com support](https://www.payusatax.com/contact.aspx) and explain the situation.

From the [payUSAtax.com support FAQ](https://www.payusatax.com/faq.aspx#38):

> 38. **I used your service and received a non-payment notification from the IRS?**
>
> Please verify your prior payment through this service by selecting the payment verification link. Within the payment verification link, you will enter your prior payment amount and social security number or employer identification number. Your confirmation number and payment date/time will be returned. If your payment was successful, please select the Contact Us link by clicking Support at the top of the page and notify us of your non-payment notification.

Comment: It was not a phishing attempt on my part I guess, since the payment has been verified by payUSAtax.com . Does me paying for the wrong from matter? 1040 instead of 1040NR-EZ?

Comment: @Huga I have no idea if you did something wrong when paying or not, but the people at payUSAtax.com support should be able to help.

Comment: Hi guys! How was your experience with payUSAtax.com? Did you manage to contact their support? I just payed all my 1040 using their services, and Im a bit afraid after reading some reviews online